# How to fix Invalid method Varien_Object::save() in product saving?

Tags: product, collection, exception, save

I got following error when tried to save product from collection:

> Invalid method Varien_Object::save(Array())

And here is full code (I know, that it is ugly, but now I try refactor it):

```
public function postAction()
{
    $sku = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
    $file = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('file');

    if (empty($sku) or empty($file)) {
        echo "FALSE";
        return;
    }

    $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . "/media/photosimport/";
    $filepath = $path . $file;
    $img_save_mode = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    if (!$product->getId()) {
        echo "FALSE";
        return;
    }

    Mage::log($sku . ' =>' . $product->getName(), null, 'photosimport.log');

    $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $filenameArray = explode("_",$filename); //0 - SKU, 1 - image name
    $imagename = (isset($filenameArray[1]) && !empty($filenameArray[1])) ? $filenameArray[1] : null;
    $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $galleryData = $prod->getData('media_gallery');

    foreach ($galleryData['images'] as $galleryImage)
    {
        $gf = explode("/", $galleryImage['file']);
        if ($gf[count($gf) - 1] == $file) {
            echo "UPDATE";
            unlink(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/media/catalog/product' . $galleryImage['file']);
            rename($filepath, Mage::getBaseDir() . '/media/catalog/product' . $galleryImage['file']);
            @unlink($filepath);
        }
    }
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        try {
            if (empty($imagename)) {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $img_save_mode, true, false);
            } else {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, false, true, false);
            }
            Mage::log($sku . ' ok', null, 'photosimport.log');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log('error: ' . $e->getMessage(), null, 'photosimport.log');
            echo "FALSE";
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Mage::log(
            'Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: '.$filepath,
            null,
            'photosimport.log'
        );
        echo "FALSE";
        return;
    }

    try {
        $product->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    @unlink($filepath);
    echo "OK";
}
```

Please, help me to fix that! I tried to use saveAttribute via resource model, but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue at  `product exits or not.When you have  use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku) then as per as`OOP concept , `$product` was `gave an object` that means' !$product goes to false ` .

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    if (!$product) {
        echo "FALSE";
        return;
    }
```

In this case,you need `to use getId()`.when a **product is not exits then it getId() getter function give the value blank**

```
 if (!$product->getId()) {
                echo "FALSE";
                return;
            }
// load the product object properly

    $id=$product->getId();
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)
```

Comment: thank you! Fixed and updated code, but this doesn't fix main problem, still get exception on save()

Comment: update.....please check.ed..

Comment: still doesn't work, I updated code, please, check it.

Comment: please check compiler and it may compiler issue.Admin>Tool>Compiler

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You can't save a product that has been loaded via `loadByAttribute`. You have to execute `load($id)` on that product as suggested in first answer.
So use this code to load and save the product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
if ($product === false) {
    return;
}
$product->load($product->getId());
//...
$product->save();
```

### Problem

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract->loadByAttribute` uses collection-loading on collection `catalog/product_collection` with a limit of 1.

Stock items of products in that collection are loaded via the event observer `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->addStockStatusToCollection` which listens to event `catalog_product_collection_load_after`. `addStockStatusToCollection` loads stock items of products only if flag `require_stock_items` is set `true`.

In case of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract->loadByAttribute` this flag isn't set so we end up with `$product->_data['stock_item']` being of type `Varien_Object` (see `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status` lines 488-491).

This causes error

> Invalid method Varien_Object::save...

on `$product->save`.